# Basic image editor (open file, crop, save to new file) in a Java Tapestry web application

Tags: java, image, image-processing, image-editing

I am researching the best way to implement a basic online image editor for a Java Tapestry web application. The functions I am looking for are:

1) Open a user-supplied file

2) Offer an editing window with functionality to crop the image, or add colour-filled shapes to obscure parts of the image

3) Save out the edited or unedited result with a new file name to a location on the server.

I would prefer a front-end that doesn't provide a heavy client-side load, and one with either minimal editing options or the ability to turn off unnecessary features. I would also prefer that it be possible to get it work on mobile devices, so Flash is not really a viable option.

Does anyone have experience or advice to offer for ImageMagick, the JH Image Processing libraries (http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html) or other options?

Answer (score 0):

The [Catalano Framework](http://code.google.com/p/catalano-framework/) is a framework for scientific computing for Java and Android.

Example:

```
FastBitmap fb = new FastBitmap(bufferedImage);

// Sepia effect.
Sepia sepia = new Sepia();
sepia.applyInPlace(fb);

// Crop
int startX = 10;
int startY = 10;
int newWidth = 100;
int newHeight = 100;

Crop crop = new Crop(startX, startY, newWidth, newHeight);
crop.applyInPlace(fb);
```

...and much more.